# Consulta ha base de datos en mysql no es optima por que son muchos registros

Tags: php, mysql, datatable

se hace una consulta con php a mysql, el problema radica que la consulta es de 100.000 registros y cuando muestro la tabla con php y el plugin de datatable tarda mucho tiempo en cargar  intente hacerlo con ajax, pero la me da error, básicamente me gustaría es primero mejorar la consulta y hacerla por bloques por ejemplo de 200 en 200... inicialmentoeno necesito que se muestren todos los registros, pero si necesito que mientras se va navegando en la paginación de la tabla si estén todos los datos
código en php

```
$Rnc_Empresa_Cliente = $_SESSION["RncEmpresaUsuario"];
$clientes = ControladorClientes::ctrMostrarClientes($Rnc_Empresa_Cliente);

static public function ctrMostrarClientes($Rnc_Empresa_Cliente){

$tabla = "clientes_empresas";
$taRncEmpresaClientes = "Rnc_Empresa_Cliente";
$respuesta = ModeloClientes::mdlMostrarClientes($tabla, $taRncEmpresaClientes, $Rnc_Empresa_Cliente);

        return $respuesta;



    }

static public function mdlMostrarClientes($tabla, $taRncEmpresaClientes, $Rnc_Empresa_Cliente){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $taRncEmpresaClientes = :$taRncEmpresaClientes ORDER BY Nombre_Cliente");

    
        $stmt -> bindParam(":".$taRncEmpresaClientes, $Rnc_Empresa_Cliente, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    

        $stmt -> execute();

        return $stmt -> fetchAll();
        $stmt -> close();
        $stmt = null;


    }/*CIERRO FUNCION MOSTRAR CLIENTES*/



   foreach ($clientes as $key => $value) {
            echo '<tr>
                    <td>'.($key+1).'</td>
                    <td>'.$value["Nombre_Cliente"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$value["Documento"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$value["Email"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$value["Telefono"].'</td>
                     <td>'.$value["Direccion"].'</td>
                     <td>'.$value["Fecha_Nacimiento"].'</td>
                     <td>'.$value["Compras"].'</td>
                     <td>'.$value["Ultima_Compra"].'</td>
                      
                    <td>
                   <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-warning btnEditarCliente btn-xs" idCliente="'.$value["id"].'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditarCliente"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                          <button class="btn btn-danger btnEliminarCliente btn-xs" idCliente="'.$value["id"].'"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                                             

                        </div>
                        


                      </td>             

                    </tr>';
              }
```

codigo de Datatable

```
$('.cliente').DataTable({
    
    lengthMenu : [100, 150, 200, 250, 300, -1],

        
        "DisplayLength": 100,
        "paging": true,
        "pageLength": 100,
        "processing": true,
        "deferRender": true,
        "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
              var api = this.api(), data;
 
            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
            var intVal = function ( i ) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            };
 
            // Total over all pages
            total = api
                .column( 9 )//
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
 
            // Total over this page
            pageTotal = api
                .column( 9, { page: 'current'} )//
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
 
            // Update footer
            $( api.column( 9 ).footer() ).html(pageTotal.toLocaleString("en-US"));
            
            // otra columna
             // Total over all pages
            total = api
                .column(10)
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
 
            // Total over this page
            pageTotal = api
                .column( 10, { page: 'current'} )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
 
            // Update footer
            $( api.column( 10 ).footer() ).html(pageTotal.toLocaleString("en-US"));
            // otra columna
             // Total over all pages
            total = api
                .column(11)
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
 
            // Total over this page
            pageTotal = api
                .column( 11, { page: 'current'} )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
 
            // Update footer
    $( api.column( 11 ).footer() ).html(pageTotal.toLocaleString("en-US"));
    
     total = api
                .column(12)
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
 
            // Total over this page
            pageTotal = api
                .column( 12, { page: 'current'} )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
 
            // Update footer
    $( api.column( 12 ).footer() ).html(pageTotal.toLocaleString("en-US"));
    
total = api
                .column(13)
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
 
            // Total over this page
            pageTotal = api
                .column( 13, { page: 'current'} )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
 
            // Update footer
    $( api.column( 13 ).footer() ).html(pageTotal.toLocaleString("en-US"));
    
    total = api
                .column(14)
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
 
            // Total over this page
            pageTotal = api
                .column( 14, { page: 'current'} )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
 
            // Update footer
    $( api.column( 14 ).footer() ).html(pageTotal.toLocaleString("en-US"));
    

    },
    "language": {
        
        "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
        "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
        "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
        "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
        "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
        "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
        "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
        "sInfoPostFix":    "",
        "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
        "sUrl":            "",
        "sInfoThousands":  ",",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst":    "Primero",
            "sLast":     "Último",
            "sNext":     "Siguiente",
            "sPrevious": "Anterior"
        },
        "oAria": {
            "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
            "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
        }
        
    },
        "retrieve": true,       
        "autoWidth": true,
    dom:"Blfrtip",
            buttons:[
                {extend:'excel',text:'Excel'},
                {extend:'csv',text:'CSV'}    
            ]
 });
```

Comment: Hola usa `LIMIT pos, num` en tu query, para obtener una cantidad **num** de resultados a partir de la posición **pos**, contando desde cero. Estableces una amplitud de consulta y pides la página m, vía ajax. Al consultar `pos = amplitud * pagina -1` y, muestras un páginador de modo que el usuario elija primera, anterior, siguiente, última o digite un número (muestras el valor de total de páginas) para que pueda introducir un número correcto.

Comment: Para saber cuantos registros contiene la tabla usa una consulta de mayor id o similar, o un count(id), que te de la cantidad de registros actuales para saber cuantas páginas existen y vas a reportar (numéricamente), de ese modo la consulta es rápida y no tienes overtime

Comment: gracias por contestarme tengo la ligera idea a lo te refieres pero la verdad no me quedo claro de como hacerlo, ya que en mi codigo yo pagino la tabla usando el pluging Datatable, edite la pregunta para anexar esa parte del codigo

Comment: En general no uso plugins (en particular **ignoro todo acerca de DataTable**) si necesitas ayuda para hacerlo con php y javascript **vanilla** (puros) me avisas y con gusto te indico cómo lograrlo.